# Threads to process similar strings sequentially

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, synchronization, executorservice

The problem I have is to read strings from a queue which will get updated continuously (assuming just a list of strings for simplicity):

```
String[] hostList = {"R1","R2","R3","T1","T2","T3","T4","R4","K1"};
```

I am hoping to use a data structure that stores which type of strings are being processed and let only one thread process similar strings `(Type R/K/T)`.

Thus, all similar items are processed sequentially and dissimilar items get picked up by the other threads.

This needs synchronization between threads on whether to pick a string, or let it wait on a thread processing that string type.

Please advise me on what data structures I can use, and how I can implement this using the `Java Executor Service`.

Comment: Data Structure for thread queue Type A <-Thread1<-Thread2<-Thread3<-Thread8 Type B <-Thread4<-Thread5<-Thread6<-Thread7 Type B <-Thread9

Answer (score 0):

You probably want one thread to remove the items from the list, examine the type, then queue the item to a type specific queue.  Each type then has its own queue, and its own thread that processes items on that queue.  A BlockingQueue of some sort, perhaps LinkedBlockingQueue, might be a good type of queue to use, as it is thread safe.

If you specifically want to use an ExecutorService, and you still want to separate the processing of the different types of items, then you'll need one ExecutorService per type, and the thread that removes items from the list can submit the item to the appropriate ExecutorService.  This would make more sense if you wanted to have a pool of more than one thread per type.

Comment: Yes. One executor service for every type but the types are not confined to a number. Hence, I want to have like a hashmap that adds a type and corresponding threads to wait as values. After one string is done invoke the next thread from values, and when all of them are done. Delete that entry from the hash map.

Comment: In that case, the sorting thread can start up and shut down `ExecutorService`s as required, keeping them in a hashmap mapping item type to ExecutorService.

Comment: Possible problem with this approach is that if the queue of one specific type is full, the intermediate worker will block, and other types will also not be able to advance.

Comment: If you want to be sure the sorting thread never blocks, you'll need an unlimited queue size somewhere.  Giving the blocking queues or executor services unlimited queue sizes is no worse than any other such solution.

Comment: If I use a blocking queue   
**Type R** >Thread1<-Thread2<-Thread3<-Thread8  
**Type T** >Thread4<-Thread5<-Thread6<-Thread7  
**Type K** >Thread9  **So even if I have a queue for each type, how do I wait on a blocking queue?**

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this using a BlockingQueues and an extra thread.

One BlockingQueue holds all the strings, the second holds just the strings that need to be processed sequentially, and the third holds the rest of the strings.
The extra thread loops on the [take](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take--) method of the general queue, and once its taken an item it simply stores into one of the other queues, which in turn are taken from by the appropriate threads.

An alternative solution would be to have two executor services, one created by calling `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)` and the other created any way you want it. Then the sorting thread would call [ExecutorService#Submit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) on these ExecutorServices instead of sorting into queues.

Comment: Like I said, I just took an example of List for simplicity. The strings might continuously get added to the queue, so I need to keep a track of every string. If a similar type arrives it needs to wait for the one already being processed. I can't segregate the ones that need sequence and the ones don't as entries keep coming.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple ExecutorService (some definite number) running and have their own queues to pick data from. Now,  another thread can read the incoming data and apply a good distributed hash function on the input type which returns the ExecutorService number which shall process it. The item shall be submitted to the appropriate ExecutorService for processing. The hash function has to make sure that same type of input data returns the same executorService number. This will ensure the sequential processing of data of similar types.

Comment: hash function may be a good idea to distribute if there is a exhaustive list of inputs, but unfortunately in my case there can be a very large number of types of input. (Hard to write a hash function)

Comment: You don't need to know the list beforehand. So, am assuming that the type carries certain strings which specifies the type. Now a hash function can be a basic hash function of strings which means its going to return the same hashcode for same type.  What am i missing here ?

Comment: So typically if even if we hash and get a similar type we need to give it only a single thread so they are processed in order. So, all executor services run single threads?
Also, in that case we must have more ExecutorServices than type of strings, since there are very large num of types. This might not work

Comment: @user3055952 : Yes, they will have a single thread, but no need to have more ExecutorServices than type of strings because one ES or thread can process data for multiple types. You can have some definite/configurable number of threads(ES) which you know can handle the load

Comment: How will having a single thread help?  
All services will then act as if there was no threading